# Octopress --> Heroku error env: bundle: no such file or directory

Tags: heroku, bundler, octopress

I have an Octopress blog running on Heroku using a buildpack (https://github.com/jgarber/heroku-buildpack-ruby-octopress). It was working fine up until a few days ago, when I started getting the error below on deployment (everything works fine on local). I reverted to a working git and tried to deploy again but no dice.

```
env: bundle: no such file or directory error.
```

Here is the deployment log

```
-----> Deleting 0 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Octopress app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.1)
       Installing RedCloth (4.2.9)
       Installing chunky_png (1.2.9)
       Installing fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
       Installing classifier (1.3.4)
       Installing fssm (0.2.10)
       Installing sass (3.2.13)
       Installing compass (0.12.2)
       Installing directory_watcher (1.5.1)
       Installing haml (3.1.8)
       Installing kramdown (0.14.2)
       Installing liquid (2.3.0)
       Installing maruku (0.7.0)
       Installing posix-spawn (0.3.8)
       Installing yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
       Installing pygments.rb (0.3.7)
       Installing jekyll (0.12.1)
       Installing rack (1.5.2)
       Installing rack-protection (1.5.1)
       Installing rdiscount (1.6.8)
       Installing rubypants (0.2.0)
       Installing sass-globbing (1.0.0)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sinatra (1.4.4)
       Installing stringex (1.4.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing bundler (1.3.0.pre.5)
-----> Building Octopress site
       env: bundle: No such file or directory
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'rake'
gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
gem 'rdiscount', '~> 1.6.8'
gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.3.4'
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'

group :development do
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
remote: http://rubygems.org/
specs:
  RedCloth (4.2.9)
  chunky_png (1.2.9)
  classifier (1.3.3)
    fast-stemmer (>= 1.0.0)
  compass (0.12.2)
    chunky_png (~> 1.2)
    fssm (>= 0.2.7)
    sass (~> 3.1)
  directory_watcher (1.5.1)
  fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
  fssm (0.2.10)
  haml (3.1.8)
  jekyll (0.12.1)
    classifier (~> 1.3)
    directory_watcher (~> 1.1)
    kramdown (~> 0.14)
    liquid (~> 2.3)
    maruku (~> 0.5)
    pygments.rb (~> 0.3.2)
  kramdown (0.14.2)
  liquid (2.3.0)
  maruku (0.7.0)
  posix-spawn (0.3.8)
  pygments.rb (0.3.7)
    posix-spawn (~> 0.3.6)
    yajl-ruby (~> 1.1.0)
  rack (1.5.2)
  rack-protection (1.5.1)
    rack
  rake (10.1.1)
  rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
  rdiscount (1.6.8)
  rubypants (0.2.0)
  sass (3.2.13)
  sass-globbing (1.0.0)
    sass (>= 3.1)
  sinatra (1.4.4)
    rack (~> 1.4)
    rack-protection (~> 1.4)
    tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
  stringex (1.4.0)
  tilt (1.4.1)
  yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

  PLATFORMS
    ruby

  DEPENDENCIES
    RedCloth (~> 4.2.9)
    compass (~> 0.12.2)
    haml (~> 3.1.7)
    jekyll (~> 0.12)
    liquid (~> 2.3.0)
    pygments.rb (~> 0.3.4)
    rake
    rb-fsevent (~> 0.9)
    rdiscount (~> 1.6.8)
    rubypants (~> 0.2.0)
    sass-globbing (~> 1.0.0)
    sinatra (~> 1.4.2)
    stringex (~> 1.4.0)
```

I have searched up and down but nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed and add the BUILDPACK_URL again.

```
heroku config:remove BUILDPACK_URL
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/nicholasmott/heroku-buildpack-octopress.git
```

And created a Procfile with content:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

I don't know which resolves the problem, but now it works.

I tried
Simply set the url again: Nothing.
Freeze the ruby version: Nothing.
Create a Profile without bundle: Nothing.

Then I removed the Buildpack and I got my site down. I added again the buildpack and I created a Procfile and after that it just runs :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another application and Git remote using an [updated version of the buildpack](http://www.neverstopbuilding.com/how-to-create-a-blog-with-octopress-on-heroku). It takes into account the way Heroku wants you to specify Ruby version in the Gemfile, which is new since Jason wrote his original buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing happen to me on my jekyll site when I updated my gems.

I had to roll back my heroku to the "stock" [heroku buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby). Then everything started to work again.