# Installing Octopress on windows 7 using Yari-Dependencies not loading when bundle install is executed

Tags: ruby, octopress

When you install Octopress many use rvm to switch between Ruby versions.
However, rvm does not work for Window users so Scott Muc created [Yari](https://github.com/scottmuc/yari)
After following [this](http://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/how-to-install-octopress-windows/) and [that](http://blog.zerosharp.com/setting-up-octopress-on-windows-again/), I finally overcame the [yari not found issue](https://github.com/scottmuc/yari/issues/20)
by simply restarting the Windows Power shell and making sure that my path was 
pointing to the correct ruby installation under the Yari folder. The following commands ran fine:

```
git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git octopress
cd octopress
ruby --version  # reports Ruby 1.9.3 thanks to yari
gem install bundler
```

The [bundle install command](http://bundler.io/v1.2/man/bundle-install.1.html) however starts complaining that it can't find gems to install. After some detective work, I can see that the Gemfile under Octopress is adding gems as i install them manually one by one (ugh). The [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034901/octopress-heroku-error-env-bundle-no-such-file-or-directory) seems long. I hope a ruby or Octopress expert can become my hero today :-( so I can share my knowledge and start blogging.

I just took a shot of the bottom part of the console. I have added each gem one by one.Thanks for Yari and for taking a look.

[image]

and on and on till finally...
[image]

Not sure if this is yari related but i also modified line 205 of httpresponse.rb file to: if chunked? || @header['content-length'] || @status == 304 || @status == 204. This turns off a bunch of annoying warnings that really slow down the rake preview command and causes the need for endless refresh. Especially sensitive in chrome as FF had a better response time---

Comment: I think posting the entire console results from bundler would help a lot. I'm pretty comfortable with that tool so maybe there's something in there I may notice.

Comment: Hey Scott: I gota clue here:"Oops. Install1 RubyDevKit - I downloaded DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe. Install means unzip - I unzipped into C:\_\Ruby"..See http://utumno.github.io/blog/2013/12/21/set-up-octopress-in-windows-7/ My guess is that Yari might be missing this step for newer installs..but the thing is that the guy posting had the same exact problem...

Comment: FYI, you probably just want to run `bundle show`. Yari already installs DevKit. It looks like `rake install` worked, so is everything working now?

Comment: yes scott all running. I am sure knowing ruby helps but if anyone is using rake and runs into the same issue I wouldnt want them to use as many hours as I did :-) so maybe you can link here or add a note somewhere. Glad i found rake.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem here, but the problem is the certificate (yari problem?):

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/compa
ss-0.12.2.gem)
```

You can change the file GemFile of octopress without https and it works

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0.7'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.3.4'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.2'
  gem 'sass', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
  gem 'directory_watcher', '1.4.1'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'
```

more info:
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html